# Child Sites left menu is not updated in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I deleted and added new subsites for my sharepoint site, however the child sites left menu (shown below) is not updated in Sharepoint online. Not sure what is the problem of not updating this menu automatically.

[image]

Comment: If this is in the Modern UI, it may be search based. Wait 20 minutes or more and check again.

Comment: It has been like that for a week.

Comment: Has this auto-updated before? It looks like a manual entry in your Quick Launch or Navigation Settings options.

Comment: it is autogenerated when I use "Structural Navigation: Display only the navigation items below the current site" in the navigation

Comment: Ok. I have not see this before. As an experiment, go to Navigation and uncheck "Show subsites", click OK, and then go back in and recheck it.

Comment: Already tried that, not working

Comment: try to show and hide sub sites from navigation